# mod-rewrite help going from /2103/ to /

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have a website that was coded as http://mywebsite.com/2013/ and developed as a wordpress website.

i am fixing the site this week to remove the 2013 from the address and get it back to the way it should be of http://mywebsite.com/

however, i need to code the mod-rewrite to take the 2013 address that people might have saved and rewrite it for the correct version.

ie:

```
http://mywebsite.com/2013/about-us-page
```

would become

```
http://mywebsite.com/about-us-page
```

any suggestions or help with this ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this rule just below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteRule ^2013/(.+)$ /$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```